# Was the abrupt cut to the eyecatch in the Funimation version of episode 2 of Kuusen Madoushi a production error?

Tags: sky-wizards-academy, funimation

The Funimation simulcast of episode 2 of Kuusen Madoushi featured a very abrupt transition at the half-way point - Kanata was in the middle of a sentence (確かに、俺… / *tashika ni, ore...*) when he was cut off by the eyecatch. His being cut off was not humorous, so it doesn't seem like it was intentional.

Was this a production error? If so, whose fault was it - Funimation or someone further upstream?

Answer (score 6):

Okay, yeah, the schmucks at Funimation messed this one up. The versions of this episode that aired on [TOKYO MX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Metropolitan_Television) and [SUN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Television) both don't have the abrupt cut - there's about 20 seconds of content missing. Here's a webm of the missing content, taken from the MX raws: http://webmshare.com/play/7D8wK.

Basically, Kanata tells them that he's too strong for them. Misora asks what they're going to be doing for training today. Kanata replies that they'll be playing tag, to which they all respond in shock.

Given that this didn't happen in the versions of the show that aired in Japan, I blame this on Funimation.

Comment: FYI, the webm file seems dead.